# partial view not showing

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, partial-page-refresh

i have a partial view named "_PartialPage1" under "X" controller.
here's the content of my partial view:

```
<div>Hello</div>
```

my X controller contains this:

```
    public ActionResult _PartialPage1()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

in my home index, i have this:

```
 <div style="float:left"> @Ajax.ActionLink("Call X", "_PartialPage1", "X", new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "divToUpdate" }) </div>
 <div style="float:left"> @Ajax.ActionLink("Call Y", "_PartialPage2", "Y",new  AjaxOptions(){ UpdateTargetId = "divToUpdate" }) </div>
 <div style="float:left"> @Ajax.ActionLink("Call Z", "_PartialPage3", "Z",new  AjaxOptions(){ UpdateTargetId = "divToUpdate" }) </div>

 <div id="divToUpdate"></div>
```

when i click Call X, nothing is being shown.. i am trying to learn ajax partial page update.... hope you can help me... thanks :)

Comment: is your action being hit? Did you try returning PartialView() instead of View();

Comment: thanks... i didnt know there's a thing called PartialView... do you think i could return an Ienumerable to the PartialView? if yes, what should be included in my partial view code to accept the returned data...

Comment: If you wanted to have your partial view return an IEnumerable then in the cshtml file you'd have @model IEnumerable<YourClassType> and in your action you'd have return PartialView(anIEnumerable); If you don't return the correct model type you'd get an error which could explain why you're not seeing any results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to render a partial view you should use:

```
@Html.Partial("PartialViewName");
```

Where you have a partial view named "PartialViewName" 
with the div tag hello

Answer (score 0):

If you have

- A controller named XController containing an action named _PartialPage1
- References to both the jquery and jquery.unobtrusive-ajax javascript libraries on the page you're using
- A view in the correct folder named "_PartialPage1"
- A div with the id divToUpdate

Then your code you provided should work. I would check that all of these conditions are met. I recommend using firebug to verify that your ajax call is working. Returning a PartialView instead of a View is more appropriate, but you should see results within your div either way.